# Question of condition (sort of)

Tags: meaning, terminology, conditionals

What is the term for someone who causes/allows themselves to experience a similar pain to someone else as a way of empathizing with them or making it up to them? For example a person witnesses the assault of another person, and allows the assaulted person to attack them without resistance; as a way of making it right for the initially assaulted person? I believe there is a medical term for this, but I am not sure.

Comment: There may be a medical term of which I am unaware, but you could call the behaviour you describe _empathetic/sympathetic masochism_ or _empathetic/sympathetic martyrdom_.

Comment: i doubt there is a med term.

Comment: Could you Post some specific examples, as full English sentences?

Comment: There's a *legal* phrase, 'retributive justics', referring to penal systems where the perpetrator receives equal pain/suffering to the pain/suffering they cause. May I ask why you want a medical term or expect there to be one? Are you trying to describe the state of mind that leads people to volunteer for this?

Answer (score 0):

What about a *phantom pregnancy* in a man, also called a *sympathetic pregnancy*, when the husband of a pregnant wife, or the male partner of a pregnant female partner, experiences many of the clinical symptoms of his pregnant other-half. Case studies of "expectant" fathers have identified morning sickness, food cravings, back pain, fatigue, labor pains and in very rare cases, a swollen stomach resembling a 'baby bump'.  The condition is also known as *Couvade Syndrome* but many medical professionals do not recognize it. (BBC News)

Comment: Thank you I'll look more into it, definitely sounds interesting... Though I'm not sure if it translates into what I'm looking for; will have to do more research.

Answer (score -2):

You may be looking for the term Munchausen's syndrome [Munchausen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munchausen_syndrome)

> Munchausen syndrome is a factitious disorder wherein those affected
>   feign disease, illness, or psychological trauma to draw attention,
>   sympathy, or reassurance to themselves.

The perpetrators can also inflict disease on those for whom they are caregivers.

It doesn't quite fit your definition, where the person is supposedly doing this out of empathy.

If you want further information on up-to-date terminology, there's DSM-5-- [Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSM-5)